# Determine extension that PHP function belongs to?

Tags: php, php-extension

Sometime I find a function in the PHP manual that I want to use, but when I try to use it -  it's undefined.

How can I consistently find which extension a function belongs to? It doesn't seem to be written in the PHP manual.

For example, `mb_strlen` belongs to the `mbstring` extension.

Given A, how do I consistently find B?

Comment: The best practice is always use latest `PHP` version.

Comment: Whether or not the latest version of PHP is installed - the `mbstring` extension is not loaded by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the manual. See the sidebar on the left:

> ```
> Multibyte String
> Multibyte String Functions
> ```

Click either one of those and then go to the [introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php) to read about the extension. Then check out the [Installing/Configuring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.setup.php) page.

Comment: Ah, I see. Either I'm blind or I'm blind.